# GDI+ Generic Error ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gdi+

I am having a GDI+ generic error I've tried what everyone says which is make sure that the folder containing the image file that is being read in like so

```
  public ImageResult ProfileAsset(string profile, int width, int height) {
            PhotoDB imgstr = new PhotoDB();

            Image FullsizeImage = Image.FromFile(
                imgstr.getFilePath(profile, false, PhotoDB.PhotoSize.None)
                );


            Image cropedImage = imgstr.Crop(FullsizeImage, width, width, PhotoDB.AnchorPosition.Center);
            return new ImageResult { Image = cropedImage, ImageFormat = ImageFormat.Png };
        }
```

I have set the permissions on that folder to everyone but still get this error?

Any ideas why?

> A generic error occurred in GDI+. 
>   Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the
>   current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException:
>   A generic error occurred in GDI+.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated
>   during the execution of the current
>   web request. Information regarding the
>   origin and location of the exception
>   can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ExternalException (0x80004005): A
>   generic error occurred in GDI+.]
>   System.Drawing.Image.Save(Stream
>   stream, ImageCodecInfo encoder,
>   EncoderParameters encoderParams)
>   +378002    System.Drawing.Image.Save(Stream
>   stream, ImageFormat format) +36
>   Havana.ImageResult.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext
>   context) in C:\DropBox\My
>   Dropbox\Havana\Havana.MVC\Infrastructure\ImageResult.cs:44
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionResult
>   actionResult) +10
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass11.b__e()
>   +20    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter
>   filter, ResultExecutingContext
>   preContext, Func`1 continuation) +251 
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass13.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__10()
>   +19    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters,
>   ActionResult actionResult) +178
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName)
>   +399    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
>   +126    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext
>   requestContext) +27
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext
>   requestContext) +7
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext) +151
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   httpContext) +57
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   httpContext) +7
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +181    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
>   step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>   +75

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution to this, generally the rule of thumb and all of the stuff I have found point it's finger to security rights to the folder you are are reading the image from. However this is not always the case.

It wasn't until I actually went up into the server via my remote access, and stepped through the code to see where it was getting the GDI+ Generic Exception... that I was able to find a great article on Rick Strahl's blog with my solution.
[Common problems with rendiering bitmaps into ASP.NET Output stream](http://www.west-wind.com/WebLog/posts/8230.aspx)

Basically it comes down to you got to make sure to dispose the original object when done with it.
for instance in my ImageResult action I  did this

```
    Image FullsizeImage = Image.FromFile(
        imgstr.getFilePath(profile, false, PhotoDB.PhotoSize.None)
        );


    Image cropedImage = imgstr.Crop(FullsizeImage, width, width, PhotoDB.AnchorPosition.Center);
    FullsizeImage.Dispose();
```

Notice after I use it and put it into croppedImage I dispose of it.. I didn't do this before.. and so I was getting the GDI+ exception

Comment: Note: You should be using the Using statement, eg `using(var FullsizeImage = Image.FromFile(..)) {  croppedImage = ... }`, and no need to call .Dispose() manually. The benefit is cleaner code, plus if something throws an exception in the block it'll still get disposed.