# Generic GDI+ error on one machine, but not the other

Tags: c#, .net, exception, gdi+

I'm getting a generic GDI+ error when trying to save a Bitmap to a MemoryStream with an ImageFormat parameter.

The odd thing is that this only happens on one of my computers, but not the others. The only difference I've noticed is that the computer getting the exception also needs the following in the App.config file:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
   <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
```

Without this, it can't start the application (which is just a Managed Windows Service). Both computers have the same .NET version as far as I can tell, though I might not be checking correctly. What could be causing this?

**edit:** I didn't include the code because I was almost certain that this was being caused by something else. Either way, here's a snippet of where the exception gets thrown:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
Image image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(fullpath))); //JPG
image.Save(stream, image.RawFormat); //works fine
//image.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png); //throws generic GDI+ error
```

I should also mention that the machine that gets the exception is running 32 bit Vista, while the others that don't are running 64 bit Windows 7. Each machine compiles the application itself before running it.

Most importantly, all machines have `useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"` in their App.config files, though only the one getting the GDI+ error is the one that absolutely needs it.

Also, here are the .NET versions I've got installed on both machines:

**Can run, using 64 bit Windows 7:** 1.0.3705, 1.1.4322, 2.0.50727, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0.30319, *Framework64: 2.0.50727, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0.30319*

**Gets error, using 32 bit Vista:** 1.0.3705, 1.1.4322, 2.0.50727, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0.30319

Comment: @Hans : That is not what I'm asking. Please read the question carefully, thanks!

Comment: Which version of .NET is the assembly compiled with? Which versions of .NET are installed on each machine?

Comment: @Joe : The target framework is set to ".NET Framework 4" within VS2010. All machines also have the same version of .NET installed, which is v4.0.30319. Only the machine getting the exception needs "useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy" in the App.config, though. I thought that perhaps if I got it to run without that setting, I might solve the issue.

Comment: Can you provide us with a short but complete snippet of code that demonstrates the problem?  There's really not much we can do without it.

Comment: @rafale firstly I would advise you read this and Rick Strahl's post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178298/gdi-generic-error-asp-net-mvc, secondly Generic GDI errors is such a big topic you should atleast post the stacktrace as there are a plethora of threads on the net, thridly you need to provide a bare bone sample that reproduces the problem, if you can do that then atleast if we cant help you Microsoft PSS will be able to take a look at it, make it under 10 lines.

Comment: Can you try compiling for just x86 instead of any machine, and see if that changes which machines are throwing the error? Would help in debugging.

Comment: GDI+ itself is in a DLL that's provided with the operating system (System.Drawing is just a wrapper over it), so the fact you're getting different results on different OSes could mean that there's a bug in the Vista version of the GDI+ DLL. Is the Vista machine running the latest service pack? Are there any relevant-looking Windows updates that you could install?

Answer (score 5):

You're not giving us much to go on, but I'm going to use my psychic debugging powers.

I'm guessing that the computer that doesn't get the exception -- let's call it computer A -- has .NET 2.0, 3.0, and/or 3.5 installed (and possibly .NET 4.0 as well; that doesn't really matter here). And I'm also guessing that the assembly that gets the exception was compiled for .NET 3.5 (or 3.0 or 2.0).

I'm also guessing that the computer that does get the exception -- let's call it computer B -- does not have .NET 3.5 installed, but does have .NET 4.0. (That being the only reason I know of that would require the app.config entries you posted.)

Let me further hazard a guess that both machines are running the same OS, and the same bit-ness of OS (both 32-bit OSes, or both 64-bit OSes). I'm going out on a limb here, but I would *hope* that if they were different, that you would have included this sort of crucial detail when asking your question.

If all those guesses are correct, then the obvious conclusion is that .NET changed its behavior between the 2.0 .NET runtime (which is what's being used on computer A, because .NET 2.0, 3.0, and 3.5 all run on the 2.0 runtime) and the 4.0 .NET runtime (which is what's being used on computer B, because you specifically requested it in your app.config). .NET 4.0 throws an exception when you try to do whatever you're doing, and .NET 3.5 did not.

The obvious next question is "why does it throw an exception?", but you haven't given us anywhere *near* enough information to try to guess at that.

Comment: I've added some more details to my original post, including a code snippet. Apologies for not including that earlier.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows Vista, GDI+ used its own image codecs. In Windows 7, GDI+ uses [WIC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee719654.aspx). This is likely the cause of the difference in behavior.

Comment: Interesting point. I'll do some more tests to see if that is indeed the case.